# Authenticate Facebook User ID and Access Token Server Side

Tags: c#, facebook, c#-4.0

I am using the Facebook Javascript SDK on my site to authenticate a user.  So I get their ID and their access token.  On the back-end I want to validate this information and make sure the token is still valid.

What is the easiest way to this in c#.

Answer (score 6):

This is super easy to do with the C# facebook SDK - All of one line of code :)

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
```

http://docs.csharpsdk.org/docs/making-synchronous-requests.html